# Flutter child widget is rebuilding with wrong Theme.of(context).color

Tags: flutter, state

After changing color and setting the state of the whole screen, everything rebuilds with the right theme except for the expansion tile (which has the same parent as the list view you see). The expansion tile is a my own widget that I created, where I copied the code of the original expansion tile and just changed the icon direction.
If I switch to a different tab and comeback it's updated and has the right theme.
I am using CupertinoTheme.of(context).barBackgroundColor and this works for all other widgets just fine on updating.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1V0a.png)
This picture shows how the expansion tile at the bottom still has the dark theme after rebuilding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFA3h.png)
This picture shows the TodaysWorkoutListVIewBuilder() which updates just fine and the TodaysCardioListViewBuilder(), which doesn't update the Theme correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLwlJ.png)
Here you can see the usage of the ExpansionTile inside the TodaysCardioListViewBuilder() and when I print the color at the beginning of building this I get the right color(white), but the Expansion Tile collapsed background is still black.

If you have any ideas where I went wrong please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but will leave this on here in case somebody has the same issue.
The error was that `MyCupertinoExpansionTile` didn't have a key, so it wasn't rebuilding. The solution was to just add the parameter key to the widget:

```
MyCupertinoExpansionTile(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  ...
),
```